# Spring HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration creation failed when AOP logging is enabled

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I have spring boot based application I have configured the Annotation based transaction management using Spring data jpa
When AOP is added application is failing to start with below error

```
@Bean
public PerfAnalyzerAspect loggingAspect() {
    return new PerfAnalyzerAspect();
}

@Around("demoPointcut()")
public Object perfLoggingAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

    final StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    stopWatch.start(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());

    try {
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    } finally {
        stopWatch.stop();
        logTimeTaken
    }

}


@Pointcut("execution(* com.test.*(..))")
public void demoPointcut() {}

2016-06-30 18:16:17,029 INFO  com.jpmc.event.central.EventCentralMain main - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-06-30 18:16:19,861 WARN  org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext main - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.jpmc.event.central.listener [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
2016-06-30 18:16:19,862 ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication main - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.jpmc.event.central.listener [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at com.jpmc.event.central.EventCentralMain.main(EventCentralMain.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.jpmc.event.central.listener [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:85)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.jpmc.event.central.listener [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.spri
```

Entity manager is configured as below

```
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { env.getProperty(Constants.entityBasePackage) });
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        return entityManager;
    }
```

Please let us know is there any change I need to do in the way I load the configurations

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAdminServer
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyApp.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.LOG);
        app.run(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like your @Pointcut will proxy every public method everywhere. You neeed to be more specific, and I bet it will work after that.

Comment: looks like you have a circular reference. Are you trying to declare your @Bean inside your PerfAnalyzerAspect class? (can you show me the whole class?)

Comment: I understand circular reference issue but actual issue I am facing is because of transaction configuration

Answer (score 0):

I could configure with annotation based approach

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(com.test.aop.ProfileExecution)")
```

however below mentioned configuration is still failing

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.test.*(..))")
```